# RXJS: Interceptor that switch token in every request (with NGRX)

Tags: angular, rxjs, jwt, ngrx, interceptor

I made an interceptor that have the following logic:

1) I am taking the current token and send it in the header.

2) In the response i take the new token from the header response and save it in the state.

The problem is, if the request goes one after another so the first response didn't came back(with new token), but second is already sent with the old token.

Here is the code:

```
 this.authFacade.syncToken$.pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap(syncToken => {
          const requestWithToken = request.clone({
            headers: request.headers.set(AUTH_HEADER_NAME, TOKEN_PREFIX + syncToken),
          });

          return next.handle(requestWithToken).pipe(
            tap((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
              if (response.headers && response.headers.get(SET_AUTH_HEADER_NAME)) {

                this.authFacade.setSyncToken(response.headers.get(SET_AUTH_HEADER_NAME)!);
              }
            })
          );
        }),
      );
```

The authFacade:

```
  public readonly syncToken$ = this.store$.select(selectSyncToken);

  public setSyncToken(syncToken: string) {
    this.store$.dispatch(authActions.setSyncToken({syncToken}));
  }
```

Any elegant solution for this?

Comment: Based on your description, I'd queue up the requests until the request whose response holds the new token resolves. Could you give some more context, like when do you know what request `N` is responsible for the new token, so that `N - 1`, `N-2` are queued up properly?

Comment: Hi, didn’t get your question about N, N-1..., 1. In the server there is logic that checks the sent token and responding with new token in the header. So the next we send a new request we must use this new token.

Comment: So you don’t know which request has the “invalid” token, right?

Comment: All i need is to queue the requests, so the token will be updated